# How to manage build.<username>.properties file content with Liferay IDE?

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-ide

I have this file of following content

```
#Managed by Liferay IDE (remove this comment to prevent future updates)
#Tue Jan 24 22:42:39 MSK 2012
app.server.portal.dir = D:\\APPS\\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1\\tomcat-7.0.23\\webapps\\ROOT
app.server.lib.global.dir = D:\\APPS\\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1\\tomcat-7.0.23\\lib\\ext
app.server.deploy.dir = D:\\APPS\\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1\\tomcat-7.0.23\\webapps
app.server.type = tomcat
app.server.dir = D:\\APPS\\liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1\\tomcat-7.0.23
```

Hence I can either remove a comment and edit this file manually, or I can manage this file from Liferay IDE. Suppose I chose last option.

How to perform it? How to manage `build.<username>.properties` from within Liferay IDE (Eclipse)?

**REPHRASE**

In other words, under which circumstances the Liferay IDE writes paths into mentioned file, and where it takes these paths from?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no specific UI for maintaining this file, but there are not too many items that typically get overridden. "Managed by Liferay IDE" means that Liferay IDE manages it by itself. If you want some changes in there by yourself, you can't have IDE manage it.

Remember: This is the file with the differences to build.properties. You should not change build.properties for better maintenance during upgrades - build.username.properties contains your private settings. Start from what Liferay IDE generates for you, then change it manually if required.

Comment: So, IDE manages that file. Ok. But this file contains some paths. How IDE can imagine these paths by itself? What if I have several places where Liferay is locating, how IDE would know it? I can't believe user not involved in this process.

Comment: You configure what Liferay Portal you want to use with your project - IDE will use that data to generate this file. So, yes, you're correct: There is user interaction but not "for configuring this file", rather for configuring the environment. IDE makes sure that the required settings are present in build.username.properties when it executes some ant tasks.

Comment: So, there are several places in IDE to configure something about Liferay. For example, "Servers" tab or "Installed Liferay Plugins SDKs" section in `Preferences`. Unfortunately, I found no place where that paths in `build.<username>.properties` are coming from. Do you know where this place is?

Answer (score 0):

These values are written out from the configured Liferay Runtime that is set on a specific project.  So before the SDK is used to perform a operation on a plugin, the values from the user's configured Runtime "Window > Prefs > Servers > Runtim environments" (specifically the liferay runtimes) are saved to the build..properties before the operation is invoked.  That is if you have a project that is configured with  Liferay Portal 6.1 runtime, then that path to the runtime will be used in the properties file.

[See this code here.](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-ide/blob/master/tools/plugins/com.liferay.ide.server.core/src/com/liferay/ide/server/util/ServerUtil.java#L584)